# Angular: how to hide/show elements and change data for popover on column width change?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, frontend

I'm trying to figure out how to resolve the problem with hiding/showing elements when I'm changing the column size.

[image]

You can see - there is some user avatar and round badge with the number of other (hidden) users. After click on it popover is shown:

[image]

What I want to achieve:

1. When column width is changed then more/fewer avatars are visible and number in the round badge is changed (if all of the avatars are still not visible)
2. Data for popover is changed and it's consistent to displayed information

[image]

Let's get to the code (data is hardcoded at the moment):

Column that I talked about:

```
<div class="fixed-size-column-130">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-row">
    <div class="profile-image-holder d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center m-r-5">
      <i class="cc-icon cc-icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="diary.Approvers.length > 1" class="round-badge cc-grey-100-bg cc-grey-200-txt">
      <a [ngbPopover]="popContent" placement="right">+{{diary.Approvers.length - 1}}</a>
      <ng-template #popContent><app-approvers [approvers]="testApprovers"></app-approvers></ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Popover:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of approvers">
  <app-approver [user]="user"></app-approver>
</div>
```

Single user in popover:

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center p-3 border-bottom">
 <a class="profile-image-holder d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mr-3">
 </a>
 <div class="d-flex flex-column">
  <p class="mb-0 small-txt bold">{{user.firstName}}</p>
  <p class="mb-0 small-txt">{{user.lastName}}</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to handle this. I was thinking about ngIf directive but IMO there has to be a better way to achieve my goal. Can someone help me, please?

STACKBLITZ example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjunnt-ykjiqy

Comment: Please share the code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular)

Comment: @DeepuReghunath I was trying but even when @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap is installed I'm getting `Can't bind to 'ngbPopover' since it isn't a known property` error :(

Comment: share here (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjunnt?file=app/popover-basic.ts)[https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjunnt?file=app/popover-basic.ts]

Comment: Thanks @DeepuReghunath! I put link to the stackblitz in my edited question

Comment: It's not recommend to show and hide elements like popover with `*ngIf`, you should load it dynamically.

Comment: @ngShravil.py actually popover is dynamic - wrapper has `ngIf` becouse of this  hardcoded thing to show extra user number

Answer (score 1):

Calculate how many elements can occupy in the container. and make a subarray of profile based on this value. Call the same in the window resize

```
@HostListener("window:resize", ["$event"])
onResize(event) {
    this.totalOccupy();
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.totalOccupy();
}

totalOccupy(): any {
    let space = Math.floor(
        this.divToMeasureElement.nativeElement.offsetWidth / this.itemWidth
    );
    this.displayApprovers = this.testApprovers.slice(0, space);
}
```

Full Solution: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjunnt-erl8kw?file=app%2Fmain-column%2Fmain-column.component.html)

See the difference by resizing the output window

Comment: I would suggest using resizObserver as it is better suited and has nice polyfill if needed. Also it covers ngIf like directives resizing and won’t refrigerate calculations when not needed

Comment: Thanks @DeepuReghunath that's what I was looking for - I have only one question, what if I use my component few times at one view - then all of them will have hardcoded `#divToMeasure` and when user change other column with this id all of them will be recalculated? Is there any way to autogenerate id (using UUID for example) when component is created?

Comment: @DominikZ make a separate component and call that component where ever you need it. See the solution now. I have created a separate column component. Pass the `testApprovers` as parameres to the component